# How to update correctly the status of an order to 'completed' using woocommerce api in django

Tags: django, woocommerce, woocommerce-rest-api

I am facing with the problem of changing the status of an order from 'pending' to 'completed'. The initial status is 'pending'.

The process has to be done from a user using a form (model form of django)

I think that the logical error raises when i try to pass the fetched data from my app(from my database) back to woocommerce api.

Here is my code:

```
def form_valid(self, form, **kwargs):
        order = form.save(commit=False)
        current_order = Woo_Orders.objects.get(id=self.kwargs['pk'])
        current_order.status=order.status
        eshop=current_order.eshop
        current_order.save()


        if current_order.status == "completed" :
            wcapi = API(
        url=eshop.url,
        consumer_key=eshop.consumer_key,
        consumer_secret=eshop.consumer_secret,
        wp_api=True,
        version="wc/v2",
        query_string_auth=True,
        verify_ssl = True,
        timeout=10
    )

       data = {
             "status": "completed"
             }       

          wcapi.put("orders/current_order.oid", data)
          print(wcapi.put("orders/current_order.oid", data).json())
    return super(Woo_OrderUpdateView, self).form_valid(form)
```

My printed json is :

```
{u'message': u'\u0394\u03b5\u03bd \u03b2\u03c1\u03ad\u03b8\u03b7\u03ba\u03b5 \u03b4\u03b9\u03b1\u03b4\u03c1\u03bf\u03bc\u03ae \u03c0\u03bf\u03c5 \u03bd\u03b1 \u03c4\u03b1\u03b9\u03c1\u03b9\u03ac\u03b6\u03b5\u03b9 \u03bc\u03b5\xa0 \u03c4\u03b7 \u03b4\u03b9\u03b5\u03cd\u03b8\u03c5\u03bd\u03c3\u03b7 URL \u03ba\u03b1\u03b9 \u03c4\u03b7 \u03bc\u03ad\u03b8\u03bf\u03b4\u03bf \u03c4\u03bf\u03c5 \u03b1\u03b9\u03c4\u03ae\u03bc\u03b1\u03c4\u03bf\u03c2', u'code': u'rest_no_route', u'data': {u'status': 404}}
```

Why the status is 404?

Comment: your code is currently submitting the same order twice, once before the print command and once in the print command. Assign the response of the first one to a variable `response` and `print(response.json())`.

Comment: but 404 means 'page not found' and that makes sense since you probably want to use the url "orders/<order_id>" (e.g. "orders/494"), now your url is literally the string "orders/current_order.oid". Don't you want the order id to appear there?

Comment: btw the message returned is 'Δεν βρέθηκε διαδρομή που να ταιριάζει με\n τη διεύθυνση URL και τη μέθοδο του αιτήματος'

Comment: @dirkgroten it was a silly mistake. Finally found. Thanks for the hints. The " Δεν...αιτήματος" is Greek,sorry

Answer (score 1):

The structure of my url was wrong. I have to build the request as follows:

```
wcapi.put("orders/"+str(current_order.oid), data)
```